# Using qsort() with class pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, std, qsort

I am using the in-built function `qsort()` to sort a vector of `class item` pointers.

```
class item {
int value;
vector<char> c;
...
...
};

//Declaration of vector
vector<item*> items;

//Function Call
qsort(&items, items.size(), sizeof(item*), value_sort);

int value_sort(const void* a, const void* b)
{
item* pa = *(item**) a;
item* pb = *(item**) b;

if (pb->value < pa->value)
    return 1;
else if (pa->value < pb->value)
    return -1;
return 0;
}
```

In the debugger mode, pointers neither `pa` nor `pb` point to a valid location. Set of all data members of the `class items` pointed by either `pa` or `pb` contain garbage values. Where am I making a mistake? I am also not certain on the usage of double pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using qsort?

Comment: Are you populating the vector? It would help to see that code. As it is, you appear to be sorting an empty vector.

Comment: @Fred: Yes I am populating the vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the answers that advise using `std::sort`. But ignoring that for the moment, I think the reason for your problem is that you're passing the address of the `vector` object, not the contents of the vector.  Try this:

```
//Function Call
qsort(&items[0], items.size(), sizeof(item*), value_sort);
```

Then after you try that, go back and use `std::sort` instead. 8v)

Comment: @ajmartin: Cool. But I hope you are heeding the advice about using `std::sort`. It is cleaner, easier, and less error-prone. Used with a function object, it's likely faster as well. The compiler can take advantage of inlining, which it can't do with the function pointer approach.

Comment: Advice taken, and implemented. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `qsort` in C++, use `std::sort` instead:

```
int value_sort(item* pa, item* pb)
{
    return pa->value < pb->value;
}

std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), value_sort);
```

Comment: This looks must neater. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use std::sort from `algorithm`. It is  easy to use, type safe and faster than qsort and haven't problems with pointers :).

```
#include <algorithm>

inline bool comparisonFuncion( item *  lhs,item  * rhs)
{
    return lhs->value<rhs->value;
}

std::sort(items.begin(),items.end(),comparisonFunction);
```

Comment: `lhs` and `rhs` aren't pointers (so you'll have a syntax error), but they will need to be to match the contents of the vector.

Comment: @Fred Larson I changed in function `.` to `->` but forgot to change references to pointers. Thanks for pointing :).