# using vectors with qsort()

Tags: c++, vector, qsort

I am working on a homework assignment involving vectors using qsort(). I am able to get the code to compile, but I am receiving an error saying `Expression: vector subscript is out of range` and `Expression: Standard C++ Libraries out of range &&0` Can anyone help as to where and why my vector subscript is out of range?

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <fstream>
#include    <iomanip>
#include    <string>
#include    <vector>

using namespace std;

#include    "functions.h"

typedef vector< int >::size_type size_t;


int main( )
{
    ifstream ifs = get_ifs( );

    sort( ifs );

    return 0;
}


void sort( ifstream &ifs )
{
    vector< int > vi;
    int value;

    while( ifs >> value )
    {
        vi.push_back( value );
    }

    cout << "unsorted vi:\n" << vi << '\n';

    qsort( vi );

    cout << "\nsorted vi:\n" << vi << '\n';
}


void qsort( vector< int > &vi )
{
    int bot = 0;
    int top = vi.size() - 1;

    qsort(vi, bot, top);
}

void qsort( vector< int > &vi, size_t low, size_t high )
{


    if (low < high)
    {
        int split = partition(vi, low, high);
        qsort(vi, low, split-1);
        qsort(vi, split+1,high);
    }
    else
    {
        return ;
    }

}

size_t partition( vector<int>& vi, size_t low, size_t high )
{
    int pivot = vi[high];
    int bottom = low - 1;
    int top = high;

    bool notdone = true;
    while(notdone)
    {
        while(notdone)
        {
            bottom += 1;
            if (bottom == top)
            {
                notdone = false;
                break;
            }
            if (vi[bottom] > pivot)
            {
                vi[top] = vi[bottom];
                break;
            }
        }
        while (notdone)
        {
            top = top-1;

            if (top == bottom)
            {
                notdone = false;
                break;
            }
            if (vi[top] < pivot)
            {
                vi[bottom] = vi[top];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    vi[top] = pivot;
    return top;
}





void print_vec( const vector< int > &vi, size_t n, size_t t )
{
    cout << vi;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < t; ++i )
    {
        cout << setw( 3 ) << vi[ i ] << ' ';
    }

}


ostream &operator <<( ostream &out, const vector< int > &vi )
{
    vector< int >::const_iterator iter;

    for( iter = vi.begin( ); iter != vi.end( ); ++iter )
    {
        out << setw( 3 ) << *iter << ' ';
    }

    return out;
}


ifstream get_ifs( )                             // get input file stream
{
    string filename;                            // input file name

    cerr << "name of file to read from? ";
    cin  >> filename;

    ifstream ifs( filename, ifstream::in );
    if( ! ifs )                                 // cannot open file infilen
    {
        cerr << "cannot open input file '" << filename << "'\n";
        exit( 1 );
    }

    return ifs;                                 // return input file stream
}
```

Comment: when I run the debugger, it says that it cannot open a PDB file. I have never heard of a PDB file

Answer (score 3):

when you have partitioned your elements until you have only 1 element left in each partition, if i understand correctly you will return 0 as top.

when you hit the code `qsort(vi, low, split-1);` split will contain 0.

you need to treat the special case were your partitions have 1 elements

Answer (score 0):

Don't use qsort in C++. If possible use std::sort().

The issue is that the base you pass to qsort is not vi but &vi[0] since the container may have other data to manage the vector.

Also look at [Using qsort() with class pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925665/using-qsort-with-class-pointers) for more answers and explanations.

Comment: I am supposed to use qsort. Its for my assignment and the professor says using qsort is mandatory.

Comment: Are you using the library present in C++ or are you building your own quicksort routine ?